# How to pass inline options when running npx?

Tags: npx, npm-registry

Without changing the global npm configuration of the workstation or creating an `.npmrc` file in the current directory, I want to run an npx package using a private nexus registry.

So, is it possible to run [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) commands (preferably cross-paltform) with inline options like `registry` and `strict-ssl`? Something like:

```
npx somerunnablepackage --registry https://mynexus --strict-ssl false
```

I tried the snippet above on PowerShell/Windows, but my registry was not hit and it tried to reach the default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```bash
npm_config_registry=https://mynexus npm_config_strict_ssl=false npx somerunnablepackage
```

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/config#environment-variables

> ##### Environment Variables
>
> Any environment variables that start with `npm_config_` will be
> interpreted as a configuration parameter.  For example, putting
> `npm_config_foo=bar` in your environment will set the `foo`
> configuration parameter to `bar`.  Any environment configurations that
> are not given a value will be given the value of `true`.  Config
> values are case-insensitive, so `NPM_CONFIG_FOO=bar` will work the
> same. However, please note that inside [`scripts`](/using-npm/scripts)
> npm will set its own environment variables and Node will prefer those
> lowercase versions over any uppercase ones that you might set. For
> details see [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14528).
>
> Notice that you need to use underscores instead of dashes, so
> `--allow-same-version` would become
> `npm_config_allow_same_version=true`.

Comment: That's a 10+ page link. What part of it is relevant to your answer?

Comment: @DanielKaplan first page

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I hope you don't mind if I add the relevant text